# Greasing a roller brake in a difficult spot!

Tags: brakes, shimano, cargo, nexus, grease

I have a Gazelle cargo bike with Shimano Nexus roller brakes. I know these need to be greased fairly regularly. Unfortunately the bar from the carrier is right on top of the hole for adding the brake grease. Does anyone know of some sort of bendy tube or a way of getting the grease in the hole without dismantling the whole of the front wheel. I'm not mega bike savy so I'd not feel very confident about unscrewing the whole lot to apply the grease. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, roller brakes are very rare, so most of us are not familiar with them.  But I would probably visit a hardware store and find a bit of rubber tubing that would fit.

Comment: Can you take a photo and edit it into your question?  I have some ideas that may work.

Comment: In the 9-10 years I rode a bike with a Shimano roller brake, I never greased it. Never had any problems with it.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/51435/24228) in reply to a question about what grease to use with Shimano roller bakes, it's important to use the proper Shimano roller brake grease and to apply it into the hole properly. The Shimano grease comes in a tube with a nozzle that facilitates proper grease application.

> Very important to follow the instructions that come with the grease - main point is to insert the grease tube nozzle at least 12mm into the hole otherwise the grease will not reach the actual braking surface.

Simply pushing grease into the hole will not be effective. Some sort of extension made from rubber or flexible plastic tube would work as long as it can be inserted into the hub far enough.

I don't think you are correct in the assertion that roller brakes need to be greased often. According to the Shimano instructions grease only needs to be added when the brakes are not working well or are making noise.

Comment: Thanks not a bad idea! Its finding something that will flex but will permit the grease through which is thick. I've thought about pushing it through with a spatula.

Comment: If the tube has a nozzle then it would probably be possible to push it inside a length of rubber hose to allow grease to be forced down the hose.

Comment: For a process that has to be done rarely and involves bigger safety I should rather do it right than botch something. Better to learn how to take the wheel out and apply the nozzle as instructed by Shimano. If available, a local bike shop, a bike repair cooperative, or someone helpful will certainly help with that. If need be we may walk you though the procedure here as well.

Answer (score -2):

I have used Lucas "Red & Tacky" which is the same grease I used in my BBSHD Main gears. It is great with heat and so far 1118km is working well.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles! This site is a little different from a typical forum. The expectation here is that users give a detailed yet direct and factual explanation to the question asked, which in this case is "how do I get the grease into the roller brake", not "what kind of grease should I use." That's why this answer is getting flagged and down-voted. Please [Take the Tour](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information about how this and other Stack Exchange sites work.